# Unable to activate Windows 8

Tags: command-line, windows-8, windows-activation

I first installed **Windows 8 Pro 64 bits OEM** a few months ago. I did a clean install with the same disc and key yesterday, after installing new hardware. I remember having this very same issue with my first installation, but I am absolutely unable to remember or find what I had managed to do. I remember it wasn't one of the obvious solutions, though.

I am unable to activate Windows. In PC settings, I get "Windows cannot be activated right now. Please try again later. If the issue persists, contact your system administrator or technical support to get help." (Rough translation)

When I try to activate it through alternate methods, I get error code 0x8007007B, "The syntax of the file, directory or volume's name is incorrect." (Rough translation)

I have tried the following:

- Normal method through PC settings
- Normal method through control panel
- `slui 3` method (which tells me my key is correct when I type it, then an error when I try to do the activation)
- Running `cmd` as administrator and using `slmgr` commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling Microsoft, I discovered the disc and product key my stepfather had brought me was a volume license that can only be activated in a specific work environment, and only used there, so whatever trick I had found the first time was basically illegal. In the end, I bought a license on the last day of the upgrade discount with the upgrade assistant. Which, by the way, **can** be used with any kind of disc, and can be used in Windows 8 to activate it with a new license by running it in Windows 7 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try all steps from here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/why-activate-windows

and if this doesn't help, contact the support:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=270074

Answer (score 0):

Error 0xc004b100  / Cannot activate windows at this time

I solved this problem by rebooting, unplugging internet cable and or disconnecting from wireless. Then entered the product key and used Microsoft's phone activation. It was successfully activated.